# Can you deserialize and older version of xml into a newer structure

Tags: c#, .net, xml, deserialization, xmlserializer

I am attempting to update the objects that being deserialized. Taking one object, renaming, using parts and adding a new object that will hold the remaining objects. Is there a way in .NET to deserialize the old XML into the new format?

e.g.

Old Structure:

```
<objectinfo>
<element1></element1>
<element2></element2>
<element3></element3>
<element4></element4>
</objectinfo>
```

New Structure:

```
<objinfo>
<element1></element1>
<element2></element2>
</objinfo>  

<newobject>
<element3></element3>
<element4></element4>
</newobject>
```

Note I am using `XmlSerializer` to deserialize.

Comment: Deserialize using the old class and re-serialize using the new one?

Comment: Sure,  just deserialize the old structure into classes, copy the data into a new class structure, and serialize from the new objects.

Comment: Yes provided the schema does require the objects.  Deserialize only looks at the tags in the xml and will ignore object in the classes that do not match the xml.  In your case you changed the name of the objectinfo to objinfo which will give errors.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming you are using [`XmlSerializer`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.xml.serialization.xmlserializer?view=net-5.0) to deserialize, if your `<objectinfo>` is an immediate child of the root XML element, then deserializing to some [DTO](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Data_transfer_object) type identical to old type and mapping to the new object manually or via [automapper](/questions/tagged/automapper) solves the problem quite easily.

If, however, the objects being modified are nested deeply inside an object hierarchy being deserialized then the DTO strategy isn't as convenient because `XmlSerializer` doesn't offer a general surrogate DTO replacement mechanism.  One alternative approach in such situations is to manually handle the unknown elements in an [`XmlSerializer.UnknownElement`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.xml.serialization.xmlserializer.unknownelement?view=net-5.0) event.

To do this in a general way, introduce the following interface and extension methods for XML deserialization:

```
public interface IUnknownElementHandler
{
    void OnUnknownElement(object sender, XmlElementEventArgs e);
}

public static partial class XmlSerializationHelper
{
    public static T LoadFromXml<T>(this string xmlString, XmlSerializer serializer = null)
    {
        serializer = serializer ?? new XmlSerializer(typeof(T)).AddUnknownElementHandler();
        using (var reader = new StringReader(xmlString))
            return (T)serializer.Deserialize(reader);
    }

    public static T LoadFromFile<T>(string filename, XmlSerializer serializer = null)
    {
        serializer = serializer ?? new XmlSerializer(typeof(T)).AddUnknownElementHandler();
        using (var reader = new FileStream(filename, FileMode.Open))
            return (T)serializer.Deserialize(reader);
    }
    
    public static XmlSerializer AddUnknownElementHandler(this XmlSerializer serializer)
    {
        serializer.UnknownElement += (o, e) =>
        {
            var handler = e.ObjectBeingDeserialized as IUnknownElementHandler;
            if (handler != null)
                handler.OnUnknownElement(o, e);
        };
        return serializer;
    }
}
```

Then, assuming your new data model looks e.g. like this, where `Root` is the top-level object and `ContainerType` contains the elements being restructured:

```
[XmlRoot(ElementName = "Root")]
public class Root
{
    public ContainerType ContainerType { get; set; }
}

[XmlRoot(ElementName = "ContainerType")]
public partial class ContainerType 
{
    [XmlElement(ElementName = "objinfo")]
    public Objinfo Objinfo { get; set; }
    [XmlElement(ElementName = "newobject")]
    public Newobject Newobject { get; set; }
}

[XmlRoot(ElementName = "objinfo")]
public class Objinfo
{
    [XmlElement(ElementName = "element1")]
    public string Element1 { get; set; }
    [XmlElement(ElementName = "element2")]
    public string Element2 { get; set; }
}

[XmlRoot(ElementName = "newobject")]
public class Newobject
{
    [XmlElement(ElementName = "element3")]
    public string Element3 { get; set; }
    [XmlElement(ElementName = "element4")]
    public string Element4 { get; set; }
}
```

Add an `OnUnknownElement` handler to `ContainerType` as follows:

```
public partial class ContainerType : IUnknownElementHandler
{
    #region IUnknownElementHandler Members

    void IUnknownElementHandler.OnUnknownElement(object sender, XmlElementEventArgs e)
    {
        var container = (ContainerType)e.ObjectBeingDeserialized;
    
        var element1 = e.Element.SelectSingleNode("element1");
        var element2 = e.Element.SelectSingleNode("element2");
        
        if (element1 != null || element2 != null)
        {
            container.Objinfo = container.Objinfo ?? new Objinfo();
            if (element1 != null)
                container.Objinfo.Element1 = element1.InnerText;
            if (element2 != null)
                container.Objinfo.Element2 = element2.InnerText;
        }
        
        var element3 = e.Element.SelectSingleNode("element3");
        var element4 = e.Element.SelectSingleNode("element4");
        if (element3 != null || element4 != null)
        {
            container.Newobject = container.Newobject ?? new Newobject();
            if (element3 != null)
                container.Newobject.Element3 = element3.InnerText;
            if (element4 != null)
                container.Newobject.Element4 = element4.InnerText;
        }
    }

    #endregion
}
```

Then when you deserialize your `Root` from a file using the `LoadFromFile` method above:

```
var root = XmlSerializationHelper.LoadFromFile<Root>(filename);
```

The obsolete, unknown XML elements will postprocessed by the `ContainerType` handler.

Demo fiddle [here](https://dotnetfiddle.net/3Ularu).

Comment: Thank you. A little tweaking it and that should work.